# On iOS, can you begin work on the background thread before applicationDidEnterBackground is called?

Tags: ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm updating some content in my app and I want that to finish up when the user switches out of the app. It seems like I have to stop my currently-running update and start another one in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method. It would be much more convenient if I could mark some work as something I want to run in the background before that method is called.

Here's the scenario:

- I'm trying to update content and start running a SQL update that takes a bit of time. (More than the five seconds you have to return from `applicationDidEnterBackground`.)
- The user leaves the app. The current update is suspended, but I really want it to finish.
- I can start a new update which picks up where the other left off, but if the user switches back into the app I have SQL-level concurrency issues.

Is the only option to break down the SQL queries to smaller batches so I can switch over cleanly in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` callback? It almost doubles the execution time. (I'm not worried about the OS killing my background task, resume is handled fine.)

Ideally I'd be able to have the existing work continue seamlessly in the background (at the pleasure of the OS), is that possible? Are there better options?

(I've read the [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)'s section on executing background tasks.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue to run your current threads. You don't have to stop any of them and start new one.

The only thing which you need to do, if to use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler (as proxi mentioned) when you entering background and use endBackgroundTask when you are done. This method gives your application up to 10 minutes of execution. UI of your application won't be accessible (since a user switched to another app), but all threads of your app will continue to run. System will pause all threads when your will do endBackgroundTask or 10 minutes will expire.

I would organize it like this

- Have you processing threads running
- In applicationDidEnterBackground call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.
  Save UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier somewhere accessbile.
- At the end of your processing thread, check whether UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier isn't 0 and if it's not, call endBackgroundTask. Set UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier to zero.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you just have to wrap your long-running operation into beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler block. See the method's documentation for details on how to use it.